# Logic on a Gravity Forms redirect

Tags: php, plugin-gravity-forms

I'm setting up a series of questions and based on the answers, I am trying to redirect to a specific page. For one example, the questions have to be answer correctly, they need to be male and 65 or older. For the other, correct questions, they need to be female and 55 or older. Here is the code I am using below. I am accessing the session variables and able to print them below the questions as I move through each question.

```
add_filter( 'gform_confirmation_6', __NAMESPACE__ . '\\custom_confirmation', 10, 4 );
function custom_confirmation($confirmation, $form, $entry, $ajax) {

session_start();

      if(isset($_SESSION['form'])) {
          $result = array();
          foreach($_SESSION['form'] as $row){
          $result[] = $row;
          }

      if ($result[0] == 'Yes' &&  $result[1] == 'Male' && $result[2] >= 65 && $result[3] == 'No' && $result[5] == 'No' ) {
          $confirmation = array('redirect' => esc_url(home_url('/welcome')));
      }
      elseif($result[0] == 'Yes' && $result[1] == 'Female' && $result[2] >= 55  && $result[3] == 'No' && $result[5] == 'No' ) {
           $confirmation = array('redirect' => esc_url(home_url('/welcome')));
      } else {
          $confirmation = array('redirect' => esc_url(home_url('/sorry-you-do-not-qualify')));
      }



      return $confirmation;
     }

}
```

What am I doing wrong here? The logic is not working correctly.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Was there a question in there somewhere?   This is a Q&A site.

Comment: I added a question. Sorry, I'm new here.

Comment: Sorry if that came across as rude!  I did not intend to be.  I'll review the details and see if I can offer some guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone runs into this problem, the answer lies in the fact that gform_confirmation is fired after gform_after_submission. The logic is correct, however, the 5th session variable was not being stored before the confirmation was sent. Therefore, no variable ever equaled 'No' and it failed every time.

The solution is to call the $entry in the gform_confirmation and use it below in the conditional logic:

```
$question6 = $entry['1'];

      if(isset($_SESSION['form'])) {
          $result = array();
          foreach($_SESSION['form'] as $row){
          $result[] = $row;
          }

      if ($result[0] === 'Yes' &&  $result[1] === 'Male' &&  $result[2] >= 65 &&  $result[3] === 'No' && $question6 === 'No'  ) {
          $confirmation = array('redirect' => esc_url(home_url('/welcome')));
      }
```

Comment: Glad you solved it AND posted your solution.   Well done!

Comment: Thank you for your help! Without your nudging, I might not have discovered what exactly was going on.

Answer (score 0):

Without testing your code, I believe the problem lies in the structure of the data you are expecting from the form.  Gravity Forms will store the submitted form contents in an array like this

```
Array
(
    [form_id] => 4
    [entry_id] => 58
    [form_title] => Auto Bill Pay Form
    [form_description] => 
    [date_created] => 3/8/2015
    [date_created_usa] => 8/3/2015
    [pages] => 
    [misc] => Array
        (
            [date_time] => 2015-08-03 22:17:19
            [time_24hr] => 22:17
            [time_12hr] => 10:17pm
            [is_starred] => 0
            [is_read] => 0
            [ip] => 97.77.25.130
            [source_url] => http://example/
            [post_id] => 
            [currency] => USD
            [payment_status] => 
            [payment_date] => 
            [transaction_id] => 
            [payment_amount] => 
            [is_fulfilled] => 
            [created_by] => 1
            [transaction_type] => 
            [user_agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.125 Safari/537.36
            [status] => active
        )

    [field_descriptions] => Array
        (
            [17] => (Please enter subscriber’s name above if different than payment info)
            [1] => 
            [2] => 
            [8] => 
            [15] => Confirmation will be sent to the e-mail address we have on file when the transaction is complete. Please keep your e-mail address up-to-date.
            [9] => 
            [10] => 
            [11] => 
            [13] => 
            [12] => 
            [14] => 
        )

    [field] => Array
        (
            [17.Subscriber's Name] => George Washington
            [17] => George Washington
            [Subscriber's Name] => George Washington
```

It is a multi-dimensional array with each field having it's own ID and multiple ways to access the value submitted.

In this example, the subscriber's name field has field ID of 17.  The simplest way to access that value would be with `$form['field'][17]`.

In your code, you appear to build an array `$result[]` but you are not testing a specific field for your 'yes' result.

I would recommend a `var_dump()` of the form result first to examine the contents, find the field you want to test for a certain value and proceed from there.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I am grabbing the entry and placing it in a SESSION array. Here is the print_r of the SESSION for the questions: Array ( [0] => Yes [1] => Male [2] => 75 [3] => No [4] => Yes [5] => No )

Comment: Do you get the same array when you print_r the `$result` array?  That's what the logic is based on so I would rule that out.

Comment: Oddly, the confirmation goes through if the age ($result[2]) is equal to 65. The logic is greater than or equal to, so it must be something in that condition. Any thoughts?

Comment: Sorry no.  No typos or problems that I can see in your code that would cause that.  The only thing I can possibly think of is a type problem.  Ck a `gettype` to make sure $result[2] is indeed an integer.  http://php.net/manual/en/function.gettype.php

Comment: It comes back "string" which I'm sure is problematic.

Comment: I changed it to $age = (int)$result[2]; and access the $age variable in the logic, but it still doesn't work. It comes back as an integer. I'm not sure what the problem is now.

Comment: Try changing the field in your actual GF form to a number instead of single line text.  This will change the fieldID too so adjust your array accordingly.

Comment: It is a number field currently. I'm not sure why gravity forms would convert that into a string.